# OnTouchEvent getPointerCount() detects always 1 pointer after releasing the screen touch

Tags: android, touch-event

I was just trying to make this function work but I am having troubles. When I start the application, getPointerCount returns 0 pointers, when I touch the screen with one finger, 1. (It does recognize 2,3 4... fingers if I touch the screen with several fingers). After releasing the screen, however, it returns always 1, and if I touch with more than one finger again then it returns the right number of pointers.

Here is my simple code:

```
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        int count=event.getPointerCount();

        tv.setText(String.valueOf(count));

        return true;
    }
```

Why is not returning 0 after releasing the screen?

Thank you all

Comment: You're supposed to call invalidate() at the end of onTouchEvent() to tell the system to update the screen.

Comment: andoid [api](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getPointerCount()) says:
`The number of pointers of data contained in this event. Always >= 1.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the documentation before asking this.

[getPointerCount() always returns int which is equal or greater than 1](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getPointerCount%28%29)